# Incomprehensible parser behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Help me please! I programmed a simple parser, but it does not work correctly, and I do not know what this is connected with.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://stopgame.ru//topgames'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0', 'accept': '*/*'}
HOST = 'https://stopgame.ru'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a', class_="lent-block game-block")
    print(items)

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        items = get_content(html.text)

    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

I've got this output :

```
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the intro tour.      See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  We expect you to perform the initial triage, not simply dump your program here without any such effort.  Trace the variable values and program flow; find where the intermediate results deviate from your expectations.

Comment: Explain what is not working and what you are trying to achieve here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
items = soup.find_all('a', class_="lent-block game-block")
```

> You are trying to find out "lent-block game-block" class for anchor
>   tag  which actually is not there in html and hence you are getting
>   blank list.

Try with this div item you will get the list of matched items.

```
items = soup.find_all('div', class_="lent-block lent-main")
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. She was here: items = soup.find_all('a', class_="lent-block game-block") . If you replace "a," with "dev" everything is ok.